# How to track motion between images in a stream

Tags: .net, image-processing, motion-detection

I've got a ConcurrentQueue which is being populated with a stream of images. For simplicity's sake, assume they're frames from a webcam.

What I'd ideally like to do is detect

- if there's any motion at all
- Where the largest (by size not speed) motion is in the frame
- Where the second largest motion is in the frame

Presumably I need to composite a reference image over the last N frames (so that semi-permanent changes are accounted for eg day/night, parked cars, etc...) and then difference the current frame from the reference frame.

The frames have a (minimal) level of noise so exact colour-comparison isn't a viable option.

I'm sure I've seen tutorials on this before (culminating in a "box" around large areas of movement) but I can't find them now.

Can someone point me at a decent algorithm/tutorial?

Comment: There are many questions embedded on this one, and its scope is too large. Here is a very simple way to get you started on the first bullet point: use something as simple as the Pearson correlation coefficient (PCC). To do this the basic approach is: the initial frame starts as the base frame. Then for each new frame you calculate the PCC between it and the base frame, if the result is greater than some threshold, then you investigate possible modifications in this new frame and set it as the new base frame. Repeat for the entire video.

Comment: @mmgp I hadn't realised it was so broad? Anywway, thanks for the info, I'll have a read.

Comment: I always take imaging tasks from multiple possible situations, so they are naturally broad. Since I didn't see any kind of restrictions in your post, they are broad, by my standards. For instance, in your post you say "if there's any motion at all" and this is very broad. You  would want to ignore "noise changes", but what exactly are "noise changes" given your unknown inputs ? There are many many ways to try to detect motion changes, which can start with a simply approach by PCC as mentioned. Also, there is the fact of colorspace. You might not want to use RGB. I would go on, by the space is-

Comment: Fair enough. It's a stream of images taken from inside a building looking out into a parking lot. I want to be able to detect when someone walks past and approximate their position. So... Ignoring  noise from the camera, ignoring small movements like bushes. Ignoring over-time changes like day/night but detecting large, fast movements like people. Grayscale is fine too, I can convert the images. Does that help?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, did you try PCC and it failed for what you wanted ?

Comment: I haven't had a chance yet - I'll give it a shot over the weekend and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a solution that works, ZoneMinder or Motion are two pieces of software that run under linux using the video4linux interface.

If you need to roll your own for some reason there are a lot of techniques or strategies you can use.  You are largely on the right track with what you've outlined.  You're missing a few important details though.

1. Since the camera is stationary, keep a record of the last N frames as your "background" image.  Average them all.

   http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html
2. Subtract the background from the current image.  What you're left with we'll call the foreground.

   http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-absdiff
3. Optionally perform dilation or erosion (or both) to remove noise or join nearly connection regions.

   http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html#dilate
4. Threshold the foreground image to determine what's important and what's not.

   http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html
5. Optionally use the findContours function to get a description of what's "moved"

   http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

   Once you have the contours you can also find the bounding rectangles if that's more what you're going for.

   http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect

This will not be perfect and when debugging or optimizing you have to show output after every step to figure out what's working right and what isn't.  Spend some time building the infrastructure to make that easier.  Once you have source data and most of a working pipeline tuning to get the results you want is quite doable.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I was thinking of a different question which is related. You're quite right and thanks. I'd managed to work out a lot of the above myself but you're bang on